# Trying to post SOAP request from portable class library

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, portable-class-library

I am currently trying to write a portable class library in c# that will allow me to send SOAP POST requests to a web service.

Because you are limited in what you can reference when making a PCL, I cannot simply "Add a service reference." Instead, I am trying to manually make the SOAP request and I am getting stuck on adding headers to the `HttpWebRequest`.

My code is as follows:

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create("website_here");
    byte[] xmlStr = getPullCustInfoXml(postParameters);
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.Headers.Add() <- trying to add headers here.
```

I can't seem to add any headers because I get the error:

```
    'System.Net.Http.WebHeaderCollectionExtensions.Add(System.Net.WebHeaderCollection, string, string)' is inaccessible due to its protection level
```

Why would it be inaccessible even after I casted the request as an `HttpWebRequest`?

Is there a better way to implement SOAP requests when making a portable class library?

Comment: How did you solve your issue ? i want to do the same (write a portable class library in c# that will allow me to send SOAP request) and I'm looking for the best practice, if you pass through this post, Im interested to find out how you finally did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't get the same error message when I copy and paste your code.

Make sure `HttpWebRequest` is from `System.Net` namespace though. The documentation says `Headers.Add` methods are all public.

Also, try different overload methods. There are:

- Add(NameValueCollection)
- Add(String)
- Add(HttpRequestHeader, String)
- Add(HttpResponseHeader, String)
- Add(String, String)

More info: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webheadercollection(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Would it matter if I am writing this inside of a portable class library project? I tried using 'System.Net.HttpWebRequest' and I got the same error.

Comment: Maybe it's different .Net version? What version do you use?